# Clean up [uber-api] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I was looking at the questions tagged with [uber-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uber-api):

[They](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uber-api?page=16&sort=votes&pagesize=15) don't look well received (majority score <= 0).

[They](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/uber-api) don't look that interesting (majority unanswered).

**BUT**

Some of the questions are quite good, although some of the questions would [still look good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722121/sfsafariviewcontroller-remove-oauth2-cookie) without the `[uber-api]` tag.

What is recommended here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "clean up". Are you asking for [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)?

Comment: @BSMP "This tag indicates that the question is a call to arms, a cry for help, a request for assistance. The Stack Exchange network is in constant motion and therefore it's sometimes necessary to request help for mass-reviews and edits (not retaggings)."

Comment: @BSMP some of the questions are good but don't require the tag [uber-api], a lot of questions are not good, but there is a hazy line in between where there might be good questions about the uber-api